# Windows Phone 7 how can I Let text scrolling, the step is one pixel

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a string need show in a textblock, the text need to scrolling if it's size bigger than the size of the textblock, so the text need to scrolling, how can I let the text scrolling very smoothly?

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the `TextBlock` in a `ScrollViewer`, set `TextWrapping="Wrap"` and `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"` on the `TextBlock`.

```
    <ScrollViewer>
      <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                 Text="Bind or add your long text here." />
    </ScrollViewer>
```